# java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date Wed Mar 29 15:21:00 IST 2022. in android

Tags: android, date, datetime, date-format

I am facing an issue whenever I am trying to parse the string. Here is the code

```
val date_ = "Wed Mar 29 15:21:00 IST 2022"

const val DF_MMM_dd_HH_mm_ss_z_yyyy = "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy"

const val DF_dd_MMM_yyyy_ = "dd MMM, yyyy"

fun getDateFormatted(date: String, fromFormat: String, toFormat: String): String {
    val fromDateFormat = SimpleDateFormat(fromFormat, Locale.getDefault())
    val toDateFormat = SimpleDateFormat(toFormat, Locale.getDefault())
    return try {
        toDateFormat.format(fromDateFormat.parse(date))
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        date
    }
}
```

But I am getting java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date:"Wed Mar 29 15:21:00 IST 2022" error. How can I resolve this? Thank in advance.

Comment: have you resolved the issue?